# Alternative of WebBrowser for 3D Animation in WPF by C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, browser

I am not able to apply 3D effects on WPF's built-in WebBrowser, because it is just a thin wrapper around the native ActiveX-Webbrowser, which isn't based on WPF. I saw most of the places people suggested about one [Link](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2009/08/25/a-real-wpf-webbrowser/) ,but I m not able to make it work in my application and it is having so many dlls which I don't want. Can anybody suggest me any other good alternative solution present then?

Comment: Awesomium is the only thing I've found which will do what you want.

Comment: If I am putting this control then am not able to see the browser at least, It comes Blank..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forget to copy the needed awesomium.dll & AwesomiumProcess.exe with your executing assembly (which are not .Net assemblies).
I also have some difficulties to run with awesomium but it's not impossible.

I can recommand you the Troymium/TroymiumNet which is actively maintain by its developers.
I use it on Microsoft Surface to connect people to their facebook account.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but you could try [Berkelium](http://www.sirikata.com/wiki/index.php?title=Berkelium) with [berkelium-sharp](http://code.google.com/p/berkelium-sharp/).